# Is asking forgiveness enough if your damage someone property?

Tags: halal-haram

I have taken something from my friends.Now if I ask forgiveness from them for the this is it enough or I have to refund it?
Like I say to them "I have taken this things from you? Do you forgive without refunding?" If they forgive you without refunding will I be forgiven in akhirah?